How can I use LazyVGrid to create flexible card widths in different rows?
I want to display three cards in a single row. However, the challenge is to make the first and last cards width larger than the other two cards within the same row. The expected output is as follows.

I am using LazyVStack to achieve this but not able to add items with different width in a single column.

You can do so using Grid.
Grid {
    GridRow {
        Rectangle()
            
            .gridCellColumns(2)
        Rectangle()
        Rectangle()
            
    }
    .padding()
    .frame(height: 330)
    
    GridRow {
        Rectangle()
        Rectangle()
        Rectangle()
            .gridCellColumns(2)
    }
    .padding()
    .frame(height: 330)
}
.foregroundStyle(Color.red)

I find this guide quite helpful with Grids or the official docs.

Hello, your solution which is Grid only works for static number of row-column. If you depend on a datasource to populate your grid then LazyVGrid is the way to do so.

I have to show different cell count in iphone and Ipad  portrait mode. So its not static. I tried using LazyVGrid but it's making fixed column width for all the rows.
